# C# - Cannot find item inside the Listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView, which I will add the control dynamically in the listview.

Here is the function being called upon data binding

```
private void _DisplayItem(ListViewItem lvi)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)lvi.DataItem;

    HtmlTableCell tdCell = (HtmlTableCell)lvi.FindControl("tdCell");

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Data; 
    DataRow dr = dt.Select("[Selection Criteria]");
    int lineNo = lvi.DisplayIndex + 1;
    int idx = 0;
    foreach (DataRow d in dr)
    {
        TextBox txtRemark = new TextBox();
        txtRemark.ID = "txtRemark_" + lineNo.ToString() + "_" + idx.ToString();
        txtRemark.Text = d["REMARK"].ToString();
        idx++;
        tdCell.Controls.Add(txtRemark);
    }

    drv = null;
}
```

So inside the loop, I create a `TextBox` and assign it some ID.

Then after some processing, I want to get the value from this TextBox

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvw.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lvdi = lvw.Items[i];

    tdCell = (HtmlTableCell)lvdi.FindControl("tdCell");
    int index = 0;
    if (((CheckBox)lvdi.FindControl("chkItemLine")).Checked) 
    {
        foreach (DataRow drCustInv in drCustInvs)
        {
            // HERE the assignment to txtRemark returns NULL
            txtRemark = (TextBox)tdCell.FindControl("txtRemark_" + (i+1).ToString() + "_" + index.ToString()); 
            dr["REMARK"] = txtRemark.Text;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You seem to have a random "else" in your _DisplayItem method??

Comment: I don't understand, what random "else" ? It is a foreach loop for all lines in the listview item. For the processed one, I will only save the value of the one that is "checked".

Comment: The foreach for the datarow. I pasted the code locally to have a look and saw "else txtRemark.Text = d["REMARK"].ToString();". theres no matching "If" block.

Comment: Oh I see.. Sorry about that, I was tidying up to remove the unnecessary code. I've corrected that case. It's not the issue I think.

Comment: OK.... I can't actually see anything obviously wrong. If you do a "watch" on tdCell where you call "FindControl"...then look at the controls collection.. are there any text boxes in there? Wondering if its a problem selecting the container that your text boxes are in.. i.e., have you grabbed the correct cell..

Comment: If I change the assignment `txtRemark = (TextBox)tdCell.FindControl("txtRemark");`, it will find a textbox, but this cannot be correct, because it does not have the index. Also, even though it finds a textbox, the textbox.Text is empty, whereas it should have value that I enter from the screen.

Comment: Does the textbox have the correct ID? but just not the value?

Comment: No, the textbox actually comes from the commented out code in the aspx. So I would say it can't find the textbox.

Comment: I was thinking, whether the textbox gone when I do postback?

Comment: possibly. I use mvc at the moment.. are you using asp.net webforms? Perhaps you need to add it to the Control State as well. Not used webforms for ages though if so.

Comment: Yes I used webforms.. Ok I'll try to find out some more information about this.. My suspicion is that this dynamically generated controls are gone upon postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue is due to the value is lost upon postback.

The solution is to recreate the dynamic controls upon postback, in the `Page_Load` function.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    ListViewItem lvi;

    for (int i = 0; i < lvw.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        lvi = lvw.Items[i];

        HtmlTableCell tdCell = (HtmlTableCell)lvi.FindControl("tdCell");

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Data;
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("[Selection Criteria]");
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (DataRow d in dr)
        {
            TextBox txtRemark = new TextBox();
            txtRemark.ID = "txtRemark_" + (i+1).ToString() + "_" + idx.ToString();
            idx++;
            tdCell.Controls.Add(txtRemark);
        }
    }
}
```

The value will be populated automatically after that with the value that I input from the screen.